# Ignite put function for Cassandra malfunction in C++

Tags: c++, cassandra, ignite

I have a Cassandra table and i want to put data from Ignite cache to the Cassandra table. For that i have configured Ignite persistence and all. After that when i put the data to Cassandra using `cache.put(key,value)` only key is getting inserted to the table all value field shows as blank.  I have using strategy as `POJO`.
persistence.xml file

```
<persistence keyspace="sam" table="user_permission">
<keyPersistence class="com.test.Test" strategy="POJO">
    <partitionKey>
        <field name="id" column="id" />
    </partitionKey>
</keyPersistence>
<valuePersistence class="com.test.Test" strategy="POJO">
    <field name="desc" />
    <field name="groupid" />
</valuePersistence>
</persistence>
```

Cassandra table is looking like

```
CREATE TABLE sam.user_permission (
id text PRIMARY KEY,
desc text,
groupid text
)
```

queryEntities

```
<property name="queryEntities">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
            <property name="keyType" value="Test"/>
            <property name="valueType" value="Test"/>
            <property name="fields">
                <map>
                    <entry key="desc" value="java.lang.String"/>
                    <entry key="groupid" value="java.lang.String"/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

test.h

```
namespace ignite
{
namespace examples
{
    struct Test
    {
        Test()
        {
            // No-op.
        }
        Test(const std::string& id, const std::string& desc, const std::string& groupid) :
            id (id), desc (desc), groupid (groupid)
        {
            // No-op.
        }

        const std::string& Getid () const
        {
          return id;
        }

        const std::string& Getdesc () const
        {
          return desc;
        }

        const std::string& GetGroupid () const
        {
            return groupid;
        }

        std::string ToString()
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;

            oss << "Address [street=" << id << ", zip=" << desc<< "]";

            return oss.str();
        }

        std::string id;
        std::string desc;
        std::string groupid;
    };
}
```

}

Comment: What is in your `QueryEntity` bean?

Comment: <property name="queryEntities">
  <list>
   <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
    <property name="keyType" value="Test"/>
    <property name="valueType" value="Test"/>
    <property name="fields">
     <map>
      <entry key="desc" value="java.lang.String"/>
      <entry key="groupid" value="java.lang.String"/>
     </map>
    </property>
   </bean>
  </list>
 </property>

Comment: Now its works fine. I have made some mistakes in my `POJO` file. After correcting the errors it works absolutely fine.